# connect asp.net with postgreSQL

Tags: asp.net, postgresql

I am tryig to connect my asp.net project to a postgres database.

My webconfig file:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="con" connectionString="Driver={PostgreSQL};Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=demo;Uid=postgres;Pwd=postgres; "/>
  </connectionStrings >
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

my connection code:

```
using (NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection())
    {
        connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ToString();
```

It is throwing error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Mono.Security, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

How to solve this?
I also have install postgres odbc driver and created a system dsn. If Possible How to use that?

Answer (score -1):

Please check the link below : 
http://bytes.com/topic/postgresql/answers/778355-using-npgsql-net